# Questions about PostgreSQL version 12.2 and its compatibility with other operating systems

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I will develop a commercial Python software with the PostgreSQL database, I will use PostgreSQL version 12.2. My first question is, to run the application database (will it be a desktop application) will I need to install something related to the database on the user's computer?

And my other question is, will I be able to run my application with this version of the database on another operating system?
I saw that on the download page of version 12.2 the database only has an installer for Mac OS X and Win 64bits, will my application be compatible with other operating systems besides those two I mentioned?

I'm new to programming, thanks in advance for the clarification. <3

Comment: Will the Python code run on the end user's machine (2-tier architecture) or on a web server (3-tier architecture)?

Comment: will be a 2-tier architecture, but if it is in a 3-tier architecture, what would be the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database API driver/provider (in the case of Python probably [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/)) will have to be installed on the machine where the code runs that directly accesses the database.

In the case of a 2-tier architecture (the application is installed on the end-user machine and directly accesses the database) that driver will be installed on the end-user machine, where the Python program runs.

In the case of a 3-tier architecture (the end-user machine talks to a web server via HTTP, and the Python program that accesses the database runs in an application server on the web server machine) the driver will be installed on the application server.

There are modern architectures that are even more complicated (keyword "microservices") which few people understand well enough to use properly, but let's ignore them here for simplicity's sake. The same principle applies: whoever talks to the database directly will need to have the database driver installed.

If you install psycopg2, you will also need to install the PostgreSQL client shared library `libpq` on the same machine, because psycopg2 is linked with it and uses it.